# Is there a way to copy/move all test cases from one JIRA project to another, I have Xray plugin installed

Tags: testing, jira, testcase, jira-xray

I have tried different things and I know there are two ways of moving test cases from one Jira Project to another.
1. Manually move each test case by using option "move".
2. Exporting all the test cases in CSV format and then Import it to new project.

The problem with:
1st approach is that it is time consuming as there are thousand of test cases.
2nd approach- I don't see an option of exporting test cases in csv format, I only see xml, excel and printable. And while importing test case through "Test Importer" it only accepts csv format.

Is there a better way to move/copy test cases from one JIRA project to another?

Comment: Fairly certain you can export it to excel, open the excel file and the save as a CSV file

Answer (score 1):

You can do bulk edit and move all issues together. Here are the general steps:

- Search using a query that gives all the issues you want to move(in your case it would look something like project = MyProject AND type = Test)
- Click on the tools on top right corner and select bulk edit
- select all issues you want to edit and click next
- Select Move Issues from listed options and click next
- fill required information and Jira should start moving all selected issues

Since there is no undo option, I would recommend moving one or two issue first to see it is working as you expected before making any bulk changes.